# How can get invoice pdf using rest api in magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I  setup module of pdf using this link.  https://github.com/netz98/N98_WebapiRestPdf

I use this method for print pdf

url: http://127.0.0.1/jaipur/rest/V1/invoices/6
Method: Get

Using this method received  only invoice detail not pdf file.Please suggest how to get invoice pdf.